# Angular Calendar - click event not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, calendar

I follow the angular calendar in

https://github.com/10KB/angular-clndr

I am not able to make my click event work. I use exactly the same code in the link.

Please let me know if I miss any setup.

My code is

```
<tien-clndr class="clndr" tien-clndr-object="clndr" tien-clndr-events="events">
                <div class="clndr-controls">
                    <div class="clndr-previous-button" ng-click="clndr.back()">
                        &lsaquo;
                    </div>
                    <div class="month">
                        {{month}} {{year}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="clndr-next-button" ng-click="clndr.forward()">
                        &rsaquo;
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clndr-grid">
                    <div class="days-of-the-week">
                        <div class="header-day" ng-repeat="day in daysOfTheWeek track by $index">
                            {{day}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="days">
                        <div class="{{day.classes}}" ng-repeat="day in days">
                            <div class="event-indicator" ng-show="day.events" ng-click="showEvents(day.events)">{{day.events.length}}</div>
                            {{day.day}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </tien-clndr>
```

**controller**

```
function showEvents(data) {
                console.log("Event");
                console.log(data);
            }
```

**module.js**

angular.module('myapp',['tien.clndr']);

The injection of the module is successful. But I dont see the function showEvents called.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Your controller isn't a controller, you need to inject $scope into it and bind your functions to it for this to work, like so:

```
var calendarController = function($scope){
    $scope.showEvents = function(data){
        console.log("Event");
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

Update your module registration:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp',['tien.clndr']);
```

Register the controller:

```
myapp.controller('calendarController', calendarController);
```

Then beside where you have **ng-app="myapp"** put:

```
ng-controller="calendarController";
```

Comment: i have included all these already in my project. Still i dont see the click event handled by the controller method.